# iphone - Make a tree class with cftree

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-foundation

I want to make a tree class like NSArray with CFTree. 
(Actually NSTree doesn't exist so I'm trying to make 'NSTree like tree'.)

But CFTree seems to request certain type class. 
I want to make a general class that can deal in various class like NSArray.

Here is iPhone dev site's example.

```
static CFTreeRef CreateMyTree(CFAllocatorRef allocator) { 
    MyTreeInfo *info; 
    CFTreeContext ctx; 

    info = CFAllocatorAllocate(allocator, sizeof(MyTreeInfo), 0); 
    info->address = 0; 
    info->symbol = NULL; 
    info->countCurrent = 0; 
    info->countTotal = 0; 

    ctx.version = 0; 
    ctx.info = info; 
    ctx.retain = AllocTreeInfo; 
    ctx.release = FreeTreeInfo; 
    ctx.copyDescription = NULL; 

    return CFTreeCreate(allocator, &ctx); 
}
```

I want to use general class instead of "MyTreeInfo".
Is there any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, `CFTree` can hold any data you want. If you want to store instances of `CFType`, then just set the `retain` and `release` of the context to `CFRetain` and `CFRelease`. You can also then set `copyDescription` to `CFCopyDescription`. Something like this:

```
static CFTreeRef CreateMyTree(CFTypeRef rootObject) { 
    CFTreeContext ctx; 

    ctx.version = 0; 
    ctx.info = rootObject; 
    ctx.retain = CFRetain; 
    ctx.release = CFRelease; 
    ctx.copyDescription = CFCopyDescription; 

    return CFTreeCreate(NULL, &ctx); 
} 

...

CFStringRef string = CFSTR("foo");
CFTreeRef tree = CreateMyTree(string);
NSLog(@"%@", tree);
CFRelease(tree);
```